# Version control as a way to keep users up to date with important data changes?

Tags: ms-access, version-control, ms-office, auto-update

Ok, Not strictly programming, but here we go.

The situation.  We have 30+ staff using 2 software packages we don't have total control over.  OS is win7.

One (part a) is a 3rd party package where we can make many changes to an access .mdb database and a file tree of text files.

The other (part b) was developed for our parent company in access as a few .mdb files and a dozen or so .doc and .xls files.  We can and do change these (mostly vba code and table changes)

Both parts are changed or updated every few days or at least weekly.  When we had 10 staff it was not a big problem, but now we have 30+ and parent company wants us to move towards 100 staff.

I want to make the updates automatic rather than manual (currently we update and ask the staff to manually copy the new files over the old).

I had thought of using a version control set-up and scripts in the startup of windows logins.  This would be easy for the text file tree, but for the access .mdb and the docs/spread sheets?

We don't really need version control (but it would be nice for the text file tree), just a way to only update the changed files? That is keep only the most recent version of the binary files on the server, and version control the text files but it would be nice to have the .doc and xls files version controlled.  The access files are tools, the text and .doc/xls are data we need and use.

Any help appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Prefer open source where possible

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I've done. I have a similar number of users of an MS Access application - and so far it is working well.

1. I've created a .bat file on my network that is basically an updates script for the MS Access application. A short cut to this .bat file is on every user's desktop.
2. I've added a constant in the MS Access application to indicate what version it is.
3. I've added an entry in a configuration table that indicates the version of the database is expecting.

When the MS Access application connects to its database (this could be SQL-Server, or a shared MDB on the network), the first thing it does when it launches its main form (in the Autoexec macro) is compare the version number in the database to the constant in the application portion.

If they differ, the user is prompted with an alert to run the update script - and then they are booted from the application. It is trivial to include some check for whether the application is newer or older than the database.

Then when I deploy a new version, I increment the constant, and deploy my compiled MDE on the network in the place where the update script expects. Finally, I increment the constant in the database - and we're off to the races.

If you really want, there are methods documented on line for forcing your users out of the application as well - just in case they have not listened to your instructions to exit the application for your update window.

Comment: I've added a check for that in mine because when I run as a developer I wanted it to tell me whether I was working on a DB version that was newer (rare) or older than the one the app was set up for. For your average user, it's more than sufficient just to tell them their version is out of sync with the database they are connecting to.

Comment: One of the access db's (the one in part a) we can change the data, but not the structure as then the app using it wont run.  So no version numbers.  Also the text files cant have thier structure altered (just the data)or the app wont run.  I had thought of copying the data over at loging but it's about 90mb, and with 30 staff all logging in about the same time it would hammer or poor server.

Comment: could you not add another DB on your network drive that you control and link to that so that you can get a version number. Equally well, you could always place a file in a known location on a network drive, and check it's contents each time you start the application. Same concept... you just have to deal with files.

Comment: Basically, placing that in part B gets you most of the way there.